# escaping sed-statement in jenkinsfile

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to script a pipeline in jenkins to build a docker image and deploy it via helm to kubernetes. the version number of the chart and docker-image is a SemVer with a shortform of the git commit-hash appended. the version is stored in the env `VERSION` and the commit-hash in the env `GIT_COMMIT_SHORT`.

I want to edit the `Chart.yaml` and `values.yaml` of the helm-chart with sed to match the tag of the docker-image and chart version, e. g. `2.7.1-9fa6sof8`.

I've tried to put curly braces around the `$VERSION` and `$GIT_COMMIT_SHORT` but this didn't worked out. I tried to escape the `$` with `\` but then it won't interprete the envs.

The sed statement for editing the `Chart.yaml`:

```
sh """sed -i 's/^version: .*\$/version: $VERSION-$GIT_COMMIT_SHORT/' $CHART_NAME/Chart.yaml"""
```

the error I see in jenkins is:

> sed -i s/^version: .*$/version: 2.7.1-9fa6sof8 /
>   $CHART_NAME/Chart.yaml
>
> sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unterminated `s' command

I need the statement with the correct escapes.

Comment: Try ``"""sed -i "s/^version: .*/version: $VERSION-$GIT_COMMIT_SHORT/" $CHART_NAME/Chart.yaml"""`` or even ``"""sed -i s/^version:\\ .*/version:\\ $VERSION-$GIT_COMMIT_SHORT/ $CHART_NAME/Chart.yaml"""``

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Wiktor. The problem was that I had a new line in my `$GIT_COMMIT_SHORT` so the sed command couldnt execute properly.

The correct sed was 

`sh '''sed -i "s/^version: .*$/version: $VERSION-$GIT_COMMIT_SHORT/" $CHART_NAME/Chart.yaml'''`

Comment: You do not need `$` after `.*`.

Comment: Please check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `sed` command in triple single quotation mark like this:

```
'''sed -i "s/^version: .*/version: $VERSION-$GIT_COMMIT_SHORT/" $CHART_NAME/Chart.yaml'''
```

Usually, to interpolate variables in a `sed` command, double quotation marks are used. When no quotes are used, all spaces should be quoted, and other changes might need adding (depending on the options, context, etc).

The `.*` matches all the rest of the line and the `$` is redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

try gnu sed

```
 sed -Ei 's!^(version: ).*$!\12.7.1-9fa6sof8!' $CHART_NAME/Chart.yaml
```

i have no idea the real problem, may put up `-i` for test before use it in sh "....